# How to send messages (3 types, text only) from external service to MS Teams user; each type can be toggled ON or OFF by that user in MS Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Im new to MS Teams application development and looking for suitable solution based on the following requirements. Can I have some guidance from experts?

I have a web service, which sends emails to users based on certain activity. Eg: "Survey started", "Reminder for those who didn't complete the survey" and "when the survey results are out". On top of the email notifications, I also want to send a notification to those individuals who opt-in to receive the notification in MS Teams.

My requirements are,

- My web service should be able to send the notification to those
  opt-in users in MS Teams as a private message and not as a message in
  groups/channels.
- In MS Teams, the users should have control over which notification
  they wants to receive. For eg: "User A" can opt-in to receive a
  notification when a survey starts & survey reminders but can opt-out
  of survey results notification where as "User B" can opt-in to
  receive notifications for all three.
- opt-in and opt-out settings for specific notification should be
  configurable in the MS Teams. My web service irrespective of the
  settings, will always send the notification to MS Teams but it will
  be controlled in the MS Teams side whether to show the notification
  to the user or not based on the individual user settings.

Based on the above requirements, please advise what should I build in MS Teams. Whether "Tabs" is enough or "Bot" needs to be built or anything else.

Any guidance or suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the activity feed notification APIs in Microsoft Graph to extend this functionality.For detailed steps ,please follow below doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#understanding-the-basics-of-activity-feed-notification

Answer (score 1):

Please find below suggestions as per your requirements:

1. You can use the activity feed notification APIs in Microsoft Graph
   to extend this functionality or SDK methods:
   [Reference doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications#understanding-the-basics-of-activity-feed-notification), [Reference sample link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)

   Also you can send proactive notifications via bot to user:
   [Send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet)
2. You can create a configurable page and add it to your Tab, which
   will be visible to all users who install the bot.
3. There is no way in MS Teams which will filter or control the
   notification to send it to different users without any custom
   configuration or condition check.